# Need to understand how Bootstrap typeahead js works

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am looking for a good jQuery auto suggest list plugin. I searched Google and found many but Bootstrap typeahead plugin look pretty good. I go through the use of Bootstrap typeahead but stuck for one area to understand properly.

I read about Bootstrap typeahead use from this url **http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/**

**http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-and-asp-net-mvc---key-value-pairs/88**

here I am pasting the code which is not very clear to me:

```
("#Search").typeahead({
source: function (query, process) {
var countries = [];
map = {};

// This is going to make an HTTP post request to the controller
return $.post('/Client/CountryLookup', { query: query }, function (data) {

// Loop through and push to the array
$.each(data, function (i, country) {
map[country.Name] = country;
countries.push(country.Name);
});

// Process the details
process(countries);
});
},
updater: function (item) {
var selectedShortCode = map[item].ShortCode;

// Set the text to our selected id
$("#details").text("Selected : " + selectedShortCode);
return item;
}
```

1. I like to know when source function will be called & when it is function then some one need to call it...so who call this source function ?
2. `var countries = []; map = {};` I could understand countries is array but what is `map = {}`? why `map = {}` is required? If I omit this `map = {}` then what will happen?
3. why we need to write this line?  `map[country.Name] = country;`
4. what updater is doing and when it will called?

   updater: function (item) {
   var selectedShortCode = map[item].ShortCode;

   // Set the text to our selected id
   $("#details").text("Selected : " + selectedShortCode);
   return item;
   }
5. [image]
   the auto suggest list is showing in the picture. the div for this list will be generated by this plugin automatically or do we need to put any div in the page?
6. `<input type="text" id="Search" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Client Name" autocomplete="off" />`
   Is it mandatory data-provide="typeahead"? If I miss this attribute then plugin will work or not? Just see this url **http://www.arungudelli.com/asp-net-mvc/jquery-autocomplete-using-asp-net-mvc/** from the above url I see the person did not use `data-provide="typeahead"` attribute.
7. I have seen some people use this `remote: 'Home/GetData?q=%QUERY',` and few did not use it.

looking for explanation for my all above points. please answer point wise.

### UPDATE

8) i could understand source is an option which initialize dropdown. Effectively it is a function that you define and give to typeahead, so that it can then fetch the data to populate your dropdown list.

i like to know when `source` function will be invoked? `source` function will be invoked by typeahead when user type anything in the textbox ? am i right ?

9) i understand `map = {}` is JavaScript object but i do not understand why the person use this object in sample code. when any person is using code like this `map[country.Name] = country;` it means it is required for using typeahead.

`map[country.Name] = country;` what is the meaning of this code ? what kind of data the map object will have?

10) you said :- typeahead had different options for getting sources from different locations.. i.e. local:, remote:, prefetch: ... I think now typeahead tries to do this using bloodhound adapters, but it is rather confusing me because I don't use it much at the moment and only used v0.9 which did this all differently before.

can u plzz give a single example for each kind of sources from different locations. i need few example of usage for local:, remote:, prefetch etc.

but if u see my example then u will notice how jquery $post() function is used to fetch data, so i like to know then when person should use these approach local:, remote:, prefetch etc for fetching data ?

11) you asked for how json data would look like. so here is am pasting the data fetch from server in json format

```
{"ShortCode":"US","Name":"United States"},{"ShortCode":"CA","Name":"Canada"},
{"ShortCode":"AG","Name":"Antigua and/or Barbuda"}]
```

please give me answer for my new question. thanks

Comment: you could answer half of your questions by your self by simply trying sth. and lerning what a breakpoint is.

Comment: if i could understand all my above confusion then i wouldn't post a big question.

Comment: Which typeahead version are you using? v0.10? because typeahead has gone through a lot of breaking changes as its not yet in a release version, you should be looking here: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ for examples and here https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#api for the API, the options section in the last link will explain about what `source` is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To re-iterate my comment:**
Which typeahead version are you using? v0.10? because typeahead has gone through a lot of breaking changes as its not yet in a release version, you should be looking here: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples 
for examples 
and here 
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#options for the options and here https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#api
for the api

**To answer some of your questions.**

1) `source` is an option when initialising your dropdown for use with typeahead. Effectively it is a function that you define and give to typeahead, so that it can then fetch the data to populate your dropdown list.

2) `map = {};` initialises a map variable as an empty javascript object. {} is Javascript Object Notation (JSON). I suggest you read more into using javascript. This line is only used because the example you have is building a list of countries from the ajax post result data.. there are a lot of different ways to do what your example is doing, you could even just give the source a list of objects your self locally.

3) Again this is not to do with typeahead, it is custom code related to your example, which is creating a property on the map object that matches the `country.name` and then setting it to match the `country`

4) I don't think this `updater` options is part of typeahead any more.

5) You only need an `input` element and to call `.typeahead(..)` on that element via jquery .. typeahead will do all the rest.

6) No you can call `typeahead(..)` for the element, you don't need to use a html5 data attribute.

7) typeahead had different options for getting sources from different locations.. i.e. local:, remote:, prefetch: ... I think now typeahead tries to do this using bloodhound adapters, but it is rather confusing me because I don't use it much at the moment and only used v0.9 which did this all differently before.

Comment: thanks i go through your answer. after reading your answer again few things are not clear to me. so i add few more question as an update. please have a look to my updated question and answer when possible. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Thomas You can answer your updated questions by reading the typeahead documentation and API and then trying it out for yourself and using a browser's javascript debugging tools to place break points and using watches to see what is happening. As for this line `map[country.Name] = country`, `map` and `country` are both objects and in javascript you can add a property from a variable using array notation as shown, so if `country` is `{ Id: 1, Name: 'UK' }` then the `map` object would then have a `map.UK` property that contains that same `country` object as it's value.